# How to include a controller from jsp page

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm using Spring MVC.

I want to include menu page (named menu.jsp) with a controller (named MenuController) to my main page.
If I call http://localhost:8080/myWeb/menu.htm  everything is fine. 
But I try include menu into my main page like this :

```
<c:import url="menu.jsp"></c:import>
   Or  <c:import url="menu.htm"></c:import>
```

it shows nothing

This is config in dispatcher-servlet.xml file:

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers" />


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Where am I wrong? Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `<%@ include file="menu.jsp" %>` or `<jsp:include page="menu.jsp" />`

By the way, no controller interferes here - this happens purely in the view.

On the other hand, if you want your controller to set some data required in the menu, then you should indeed use `<c:import />`. Not however that the path there is relative to the current page. So make sure it is correct.

Comment: Thank for helped! I tried do this. But it doesnot show anything. The MenuController send some object to menu.jsp. With url-pattern above, I use  http://localhost:8080/myWeb/menu.htm, I can get object from controller. But I don't know exactly path and how to import this page. I want to set some data to menu and display in main page. What should I do?

Comment: can you ,for the experiment, import the page by its absolute path - i.e. including http://localhost. Does it work?

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it. The problem was solved when I use <c:import url="/menu.htm"></c:import>. It's mean I miss "/" for the path.

Comment: Bozho: how would you use c:import with a controller to set some data in the menu? I'm working on an app with a menu.jsp I include in all the pages, and I want certain menu items to only appear if the user has the right privilege (as set in the session context). So far, the only technique that works for me 100% of the time are good old-fashioned scriptlets; using <c:if test ... doesn't work for the initial page, and <c:import doesn't include the menu.jsp at all...

Comment: it should work - make sure you have all required data set as request or session attributes

Comment: Hey Bozho, I should have checked for your comment a long time ago :) I figured out a while later that the reason my JSTL tags weren't working was because I'd forgotten to add a taglib statement for the JSTL core library. How nice of my IDE to not point out to me that it didn't understand what any of my <c:...> tags meant...

Comment: @Bozho Hi, "if you want your controller to set some data required in the menu, then you should indeed use <c:import />", that particular jsp will also be available to public because of controller, how to avoid that ?

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered today you can trigger the controller by referencing the relative Spring url in the include.

```
<jsp:include page="/ConrollerRequestMapping/your/method/request/mapping"/>
```