# Spring MVC equivalent for Struts's "s:action" tag

Tags: spring-mvc, struts2

I have been looking for a way to embed a dynamic page into the view of another page. In the Struts world, I would use the s:action tag to embed an action into a page. What would be the equivalent in Spring MVC?

EDIT : Found the answer...duplicate of [How to include a controller from jsp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907170/how-to-include-a-controller-from-jsp-page)

Answer (score 0):

Better than using import like the solution you posted would be to use Apache Tiles or other framework like it.

So you can use templating and create the page dynamicly inserting content when needed, like menus, content, header, footer etc...