# How to do the same thing as Struts <s:action> in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, action

I would use the Struts2 `<s:action>` tag to embed an action into a page. What would be the equivalent in SpringMVC? I mean create the page dynamically inserting content when needed. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to "print" or render the jsp content inside of your current page, you can do check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907170/how-to-include-a-controller-from-jsp-page)

Otherwise, you can use another framework like Tiles, which is also supported by Spring MVC, you can see the whole information [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html)